# Saved (globally defined) array is emptied after callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asynchronous, spotify

I am using the [spotify-web-api-js](https://jmperezperez.com/spotify-web-api-js/) node module, JavaScript, and jQuery to log into a user's Spotify account and save an array of tracks to a newly created playlist, but so far I can only get a blank playlist created.

I gather all of the tracks through the API and put them in a globally defined array as I show the list to the user. This array is defined on line 39: `var song_uris = [];`
`console.log` shows that this array is filled with the URIs I need after this function, which occurs upon initial search:

```
function searchArtists(originalArtist, callback) {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
      console.log(window.location.hash);
    });
  console.log('originalArtist', originalArtist);
  $.getJSON("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=" + originalArtist, function(json) {

    $('#artist').html('<p>'+ '<img src="' + json.artists.items[0].images[2].url + '" height="100" width="100" /> ' + json.artists.items[0].name +'</p>');

    var originalArtistId = json.artists.items[0].id;
    s.getArtistRelatedArtists(originalArtistId, function(err, data) {
      relatedArtists = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < data.artists.length; i++) {
        relatedArtists[data.artists[i].id] = {};
        relatedArtists[data.artists[i].id].name = data.artists[i].name;
        relatedArtists[data.artists[i].id].id = data.artists[i].id;
      }



      var counter = 0;
      for (var id in relatedArtists) {
        relatedArtists[counter] = relatedArtists[id];
        delete relatedArtists[id];
        counter++;
      }

        async.times(counter, function(n, next) {
          console.log(n);
          console.log(relatedArtists[n].id);
          s.getArtistTopTracks(relatedArtists[n].id, "US", function (err, data2) {
            relatedArtists[n].song = data2.tracks[0].name; //sometimes this is a TypeError? idk
            relatedArtists[n].uri = data2.tracks[0].uri;

            $('#related-artist').append('<p><strong>' + relatedArtists[n].name + '</strong> -- \"' + relatedArtists[n].song + '\"</p>');
            song_uris.push(relatedArtists[n].uri);

            next(null, relatedArtists[n].uri);

          });

        }, function(err, song_uris) {


          console.log(song_uris); //array is full here

     });

   });
 });
}
```

However, as soon as people go through the optional login/callback process, I get all of the user's data (including the new playlist URI), but the `song_uris` array I had before is now empty.

```
if (params.access_token) {

          s.setAccessToken(params.access_token);
          s.getMe().then(function(data) {

            // and here it goes the user's data!!!
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.id);
            user_id = data.id;

            s.createPlaylist(user_id, {name: 'Related Artist Playlist'}).then(function(data3) {
              console.log(data3);
              playlist_id = data3.uri;
              playlist_id = playlist_id.substring(33);
              console.log(playlist_id);
              console.log(user_id);
              console.log(song_uris); //array is empty here





              s.addTracksToPlaylist(user_id, playlist_id, song_uris).then(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                });

        });
      });
    }
```

Since this is one of the parameters of the `addTracksToPlaylist` function, the XML request doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of my console, where I see a failed POST request and an `uncaught exception: object XMLHttpRequest`:

[image]

There is obviously an issue with the scope and/or async, but I can't seem to figure out where to put `addTracksToPlaylist` instead. Putting it immediately after the line where `console.log` outputs a full array either doesn't do anything (if it's within a `window.onhashchange = function ()`), or gives an error because the user and playlist are undefined before the callback (if the `addTracksToPlaylist` function is there alone).

Is the data being overwritten when the site refreshes post-callback? If so, how can I stop that so I have a full array of URIs that fit in the URL string? (According to the [Spotify Developer docs](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/), the URL should have the comma-separated list of track URIs (which was in my array) passed to it through the `uri` parameter, but because of the empty array it breaks and I get `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/account/playlists/5kxeeKym1tpEx8Trj3qkd5/tracks?uris=` (with the empty parameter). How can I solve this? Or is there an alternate way to keep the desired user flow of Search for Artist -> See List of Songs from Related Artists -> (Optional) Login To Spotify Account -> (Optional) Save List of Songs from Related Artists to New Playlist?

I've created a jsfiddle with the full JS and HTML code as well: https://jsfiddle.net/37Lkrcb1/1/

Notes: This is running on a Node.js server and I use bundle and browserify to compile the script.

Comment: Sounds like the page is being refreshed during that login/callback operation.

Comment: That makes sense. event.preventDefault(); might work in that case?

Comment: That would depend entirely on why it's getting refreshed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When a new user clicks to login, they're kicked over to Spotify's authorization page; which would obviously explain the refresh in that case. However, the page still refreshes even when i'm already logged into the Spotify web interface and therefore never see that screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like at least one path in your app will involve a page refresh you can't avoid (going to Spotify and coming back). In that case, all your variables will be reset by the page load.

If you have `song_uris` you want to persist across that reload, you can store them in `sessionStorage` (or `localStorage`) prior to the Spotify authentication, and retrieve them when the page loads.

Storing it:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("song_uris", JSON.stringify(song_uris));
// Or localStorage.setItem...
```

Retrieving it on page load:

```
var song_uris = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("song_uris") || "null");
if (!song_uris) {
    // There weren't any in storage, populate in another way or set dfeault
}
```

[Web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) is [nearly universally supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage).

Comment: This was just what I needed! I'm going to look more into web storage, because it's very useful in a variety of cases. Accepted, thanks!